# Custom timerjob uses different value then what query is set to

Tags: custom-timer-job

Part of my timerjob does

```
DateTime week = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
SPQuery mQuery = new SPQuery();
mQuery.Query = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='myDay' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='False'>" + week.Date.ToString() + "</Value></Gt></Where>";
```

"

But it always has fieldref='created' and includetime=true no matter what I do.

Edit:
  I have also tried to change the query completely but anything I put just returns null

I thought maybe it was some sort of SharePoint cache issue but I have retracted, deleted, resetISS, & deployed to find no difference.

My Solution:
  I uninstalled the assembly from the GAC ( Drive\windows\assembly\ ) then I retracted my solution, resetiss, restart-service SPTimerV4, restarted the machine. Build & deploy. Things worked again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like timer job is not getting deployed correctly,

Delete the custom timer job:
[how to delete sharepoint timer job using powershell](http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/06/02/how-to-delete-sharepoint-timer-job-using-powershell/)

Then deploy it again with your changes and see if that updates...

Comment: I have been using powershell to delete everything, although the feature event: onDeactivation only fires when disabled using the UI button. To remedy this I have been deleting each timer job via-powershell aswell as deactivating via-powershell

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've found with CAML (and this may or may not actually help you here) is that `true != TRUE` and `false != FALSE`.  I've been burned by that before. Use all caps there.

Also, `fieldRef` should be `FieldRef`.

So the CAML to try would be:

```
"<Where>" +
  "<Gt>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='myDate'/>" +
    "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + days.date.ToString() + "</Value>" +
  "</Gt>" +
"</Where>"
```